# GWT CellTable does not sort correctly if the column contains NULL cells

Tags: java, gwt

I am using a GWT CellTable and the following code does not sort correctly if the column contains NULL cells as well as cells that are not NULL:

```
columnSortHandler.setComparator(sixColumn, new Comparator<SectDtlsString>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(SectDtlsString o1, SectDtlsString o2) {
        if (o1 == o2) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Compare the Six columns.
        if (o1 != null) {
            return (o2 != null) ? o1.getsixPatrol().compareTo(o2.getsixPatrol()) : 1;
        }

        return -1;
    }
});
table.addColumnSortHandler(columnSortHandler);
```

For example:

Black, null, null, Red - does nothing. It should return - null, null, Black, Red on first select and Red, Black, null, null - on second select

Black, Red, Brown, Tawney - returns - Black, Brown, Red, Tawney on first select and - Tawney, Red, Brown, Black - on the second select (i.e., no nulls works).

I have near identical code that refers to columns that do not contain NULLs and they sort perfectly well. I copied this code from a tutorial.

This is the result after the advice:

```
                // Compare the Six columns.
                if (o1 != null) {
                    if (o1 == o2) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    if (o1.getsixPatrol() != null) {
                        if (o1.getsixPatrol() == o2.getsixPatrol()) {
                            return 0;
                        }
                        return o2 != null ? o1.getsixPatrol().compareTo(o2.getsixPatrol()) : 1;
                    }
                }

                return -1;
```

Comment: *the following code does not sort correctly* - an example of it incorrectly sorting and an example of how you would like it to sort, would aid anyone trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

First, null check is in the wrong place: `o1 == o2` will through exception if o1 is null. It should be:

```
// Compare the Six columns.
if (o1 != null) {
    if (o1 == o2) {
        return 0;
    }
    return o2 != null ? o1.getsixPatrol().compareTo(o2.getsixPatrol()) : 1;
}
```

Second, it's not enough to check that o1 and o2 are not null. You also need to check if `o1.getsixPatrol()` and `o2.getsixPatrol()` are not null before comparing them.

Comment: Your browser in SuperDev mode should tell you *why* sorting is not working. Sorting does work but your code throws an exception and terminates. Looking at such exceptions will save you a ton of time.

Comment: This is what I came up with from your advice:

Comment: // Compare the Six columns.
              if (o1 != null) {
                  if (o1 == o2) {
                      return 0;
                  }
                  if (o1.getsixPatrol() != null) {
                   if (o1.getsixPatrol() == o2.getsixPatrol()) {
                       return 0;
                   }
                   return o2 != null ? o1.getsixPatrol().compareTo(o2.getsixPatrol()) : 1;
               }
              }
                  
              return -1;